# integrate array variables into a command

Tags: arrays, bash, email, unix

MY goal is to call the following command:

```
(echo "test";uuencode testfile1.txt testfile1.txt;uuencode testfile2.txt testfile2.txt)|mail -s "subject" "recipient@domain.com"
```

calling it in the shell works as expected.

However, I would like to do so, when the uuencode commands are stored in an array:

```
ARR=("uuencode testfile1.txt testfile1.txt" "uuencode testfile2.txt testfile2.txt")
```

I've tried the following:

```
STR=$(IFS=';'; echo "${ARR[*]}");
(echo "test";"$STR")|mail -s "subject" "recipient@domain.com"
```

but I keep on getting the following error:

```
uuencode testfile1.txt testfile1.txt;uuencode testfile2.txt testfile2.txt: command not found
```

How to fix this?

I guess it is not recognizing `;` as a command separator

Comment: Storing the commands like that is fundamentally wrong. Can you give a more realistic example of multiple commands so that we can suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are storing each command as a string in the array and joining them into a larger string. You can do an `eval` on the string to execute.

```
(echo "test";eval "$STR")|mail -s "subject" "recipient@domain.com"
```